# Python: Making PhantomJS browser shut down if test terminated

Tags: python, django, selenium, phantomjs

I'm working on a Django app. I'm using Selenium together with PhantomJS for testing.

I found today that I every time I terminate the test (which I do a lot when debugging,) the PhantomJS process is still alive. This means that after a debugging session I could be left with 200 zombie PhantomJS processes!

How do I get these PhantomJS processes to terminate when I terminate the Python debug process? If there's a time delay, that works too. (i.e. have them terminate if not used for 2 minutes, that would solve my problem.)

Answer (score 3):

The usual setup is to quit the PhantomJS browser in the teardown method of the class. For example:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver import WebDriver


PHANTOMJS = (settings.BASE_DIR +
             '/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs')


class PhantomJSTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.web = WebDriver(PHANTOMJS)
        cls.web.set_window_size(1280, 1024)
        super(PhantomJSTestCase, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        screenshot_file = getattr(settings, 'E2E_SCREENSHOT_FILE', None)
        if screenshot_file:
            cls.web.get_screenshot_as_file(screenshot_file)
        cls.web.quit()
        super(PhantomJSTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()
```

If you do not use `unittest` test cases, you'll have to use the `quit` method yourself. You can use the `atexit` module to run code when the Python process terminates, for example:

```
import atexit

web = WebDriver(PHANTOMJS)
atexit.register(web.quit)
```

Comment: Doesn't help, I usually terminate the debug process to save time. I could stop doing it but I otherwise really like it so if there's a solution for that case, I'd love that. (Terminating is nicer when I make a fix in the code because there's no point in continuing running the old version of the code.)

Comment: Both options should work there. How do you terminate the python process?

Comment: My debugger has a shortcut to terminate the process (Ctrl-F5, not that it matters.) It simply stops the process immediately. In these cases, as far as I know, any `tearDown` method or `atexit` handler wouldn't be invoked.

Comment: Could you try? It would surprise me if `atexit` was not invoked at all. If it is indeed circumvented, there is not a lot you can do from Python, as Python does not even get a say on what to do when it is terminated. Your best bet then is to look at your IDE and teach it to either terminate Python gracefully, or to kill the phantomjs process itself.

Comment: Which IDE (or test runner/debugger) are you using?

Comment: Wing IDE. [Arbitrary characters added to satisfy weird Stack Overflow rules]